# Set Time Zone on MYSQL session

Tags: mysql, timezone, set

I am attempting to use the following "Select" statement to set the Session TimeZone before selecting from a Table. The Code below gives me the following exception when executed:

"You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'Select IsActive, HID as EmpNum, NameFirst, NameLast, FROM_UNIXTIME(timeIn) as Ti' at line 1"

Here is the Select statement in context:

```
private static List<EventLog> getTimeIPEventLog(String date) throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException, IllegalAccessException, InstantiationException {
    final String sql =
            "SET time_zone='UTC'; Select IsActive, HID as EmpNum, NameFirst, NameLast, FROM_UNIXTIME(timeIn) as TimeIn, FROM_UNIXTIME(timeOut) as TimeOut, @@session.time_zone TimeZone, @@global.time_zone\n" +
                    "from eventLog el\n" +
                    "join users u\n" +
                    "on (u.usersID = el.usersID)\n" +
                    "where Date(FROM_UNIXTIME(timeIn)) = '" + date + "'\n" +
                    "order by timeIn desc";

    String url = MainApp.HRMSApplicationProperties.getProperty("timeIPJDBCString") + "?user=" + MainApp.timeIPCredentials.getKey() + "&password=" + MainApp.timeIPCredentials.getValue();
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
    Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url + "&useJDBCCompliantTimezoneShift=true&useLegacyDatetimeCode=false&serverTimezone=UTC");

    Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
    ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery(sql);
    List<EventLog> list = FXCollections.observableList(new ArrayList<>(0));
    while (resultSet.next()) {
        list.add(new EventLog(resultSet.getString("EmpNum"), resultSet.getString("NameFirst"), resultSet.getString("NameLast"), resultSet.getTimestamp("TimeIn"), resultSet.getTimestamp("TimeOut"), resultSet.getString("TimeZone")));
    }
    return list;
}
```

I appreciate your assistance

Comment: `as` is missing in `@@session.time_zone TimeZone`

Comment: IrLED ... I appreciate your response, however; I do not think that's the issue. That code - may be wrong - but it reflects my last attempt which ran successfully in HeidiSQL ... I resolved by problem by porting the data to MSSQL which is its ultimate destination anyway, and with MSSQL i get the correct time by using the following: DATEADD(hour,-5,(dateadd(second ,?, '1/1/1970')))